# Clear reflection on floor surface (beginner)

Tags: rendering, light, shadows

Im aiming for the effect like this (Mint logo reflection)
[image: Mint]
but my reflections are blurred and grainy
[image: rendered]

Comment: Try reducing Roughness.

Comment: Your render samples are very low.

Comment: with roughness at zero, you shouldn't have any problems. also make sure you don't have any displacement or normal mapping, that could introduce roughness to your surface. This is at 32 samples!  https://imgur.com/a/ScKYG

Comment: Just put a glossy shader on your floor with 0 roughness, you may also need more lights in the scene. There is not much to reflect and bounce around. Try and HDRI image.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Glossy BSDF surface, and also jump your render samples yo at least minimum of 128, i'm usually using 1024, you render sample is 15, so you will not have good result

Answer (score 1):

Grainy render results usually mean that you need more samples for the render. In your case, with reflections, 600-1000 wouldn't be exceptional. And for the residual noise you can use the denoiser if you are using 2.79.

And of course, if you want sharp reflections, the reflecting surface must have a very low roughness.

What I find a bit surprising is the brightness of the white background to the text, but that might be an artifact due to the low sample number (you need the samples to 'collect' enough signal in the reflections).

Comment: I tried denoiser, it does remove graines but it makes reflection more blurry. Ill try with more samples

Comment: the denoiser is useful to remove the last bit of noise, when increasing the number of samples becomes too expensive in render time.

Comment: Samples set to 1000, rougness to 0, but its still grainy (no denoiser). https://image.ibb.co/hPg1VH/2018_03_22_17_35_05.png. Render time is not much of a problem, I could let it render 24 hours if it would produce the right effect.

Comment: Then you really should try denoising. Note that the denoising process is done after a tile and its neighbors have been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Under sampling try to set up "render" and "preview" higher maybe to 500 or 1000. 
It made a big different on one of my project.